# Is addressing a neutral noun feminine grammatical?

Tags: pronouns, determiners

I found this excerpt from *Oxford Grammar Course*:

> In modern English, countries are most often *it(s)*, though *she/her*
> is also common.
>
> - Canada has decided to increase **its/her** trade with Russia.

Is the usage of determiner **her** in the sentence above can be used in formal English? Because, as far as I know, country is considered as a neutral noun and that's what Basic English Grammar books that I've studied usually write. Or is it some ungrammatical grammar, yet very common that becomes colloquial?

Comment: "Her" could be used in a formal context, but I would consider it very old fashioned. "Its" would be the more modern choice.

Comment: People sometimes call cars or boats "she" as well. It's purely stylistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once, countries were routinely  matched with feminine pronouns in English. I believe it went along with the idea of a "mother country".

> France might see her way clear to ally with Britain.
> When she makes up her mind to act, the United Stats can be powerful.

This was the standard English usage prior to WWII. It is now a relic. No one is likely to object if "it" is used as the pronoun for a country, and some people would object or think it odd if she/her was used. I advise against using the feminine pronouns for a country.

But if you see "she" or "her" used, understand that it is a relic of a once standard usage, and do not be confused or surprised.